# Как сделать в телеграмме на python, чтобы бот мог отправлять запрос в бота и чтобы сделать пересылку

Tags: python, telegram

```
def messages(message):
    if int(message.chat.id) == int(config.owner):
        try:
            chatId=message.text.split(': ')[0]
            text=message.text.split(': ')[1]
            bot.send_message(chatId, text)
        except:
            pass
    else:
        bot.send_message(config.owner, str(message.chat.id) + ': ' + message.text)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '%s, wait please '%message.chat.username)
```

А вот к примеру можна еще переделать этот код чтобы бот мог отправлять запрос в бота а затем делать пересылку либо копирование

Comment: боты в Telegram не могут писать другим ботам

Comment: вроде можна как то в обход api, чтобы было через юзера бота